# Getting a persistent entity reference without a DB call

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to get a reference to an already persistent object for which the id is known **without a DB roundtrip**, like one would do with NHibernate using `ISession.Load(id)`?

Comment: Does `ISession.Load(id)` not retrieve from the database if it's not in cache?

Comment: @OrangeDog no, it does not. It just creates an uninitialized proxy, or retrieves the object from the session (aka 1st level cache) if already loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible if the object **is already loaded**. In case of EF Future CTP5 you can use new `Local` property of the `DbSet<T>` instance:

```
var entity = context.MySet.Local.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
```

In case of `ObjectContext` the situation is little bit complicated - you need `EntityKey` instance which is cumbersome to get when working with POCOs.

Part of my repository code:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    private readonly EntitySetBase _entitySet;
    private readonly string _entitySetName;

    protected BaseObjectContext Context { get; set; }
    protected ObjectSet<TEntity> ObjectSet { get; set; }

    public Repository(BaseObjectContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }


        Context = context;
        ObjectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();

        var container = Context.MetadataWorkspace
            .GetEntityContainer(Context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
        _entitySet = container.BaseEntitySets
            .Single(es => es.ElementType.Name == typeof (TEntity).Name);
        _entitySetName = Context.DefaultContainerName + "." + _entitySet.Name;
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery()
    {
        return ObjectSet;
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetById(long id)
    {
        TEntity entity = TryGetLocalEntity(id);

        if (entity == null)
        {
            entity = GetQuery().SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
        }

        return entity;
    }

    private TEntity TryGetLocalEntity(long id)
    {
        if (_entitySet == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var key = new EntityKey(_entitySetName, "Id", id);
        ObjectStateEntry entry;

        if (Context.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(key, out entry))
        {
            return (TEntity) entry.Entity;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

If the instance is not loaded you simply can't get the reference without querying DB. You can use dummy object creation.

CTP5 example:

```
var entity = new MyEntity { Id = id };
context.MySet.Attach(entity);
```

Pure EF4 example:

```
var entity = new MyEntity { Id = id };
context.Attach(entity);
```

or dummy object with proxy creation (CTP5 example):

CTP5 example:

```
var entity = context.MySet.Create();
enity.Id = id;
```

Pure EF4 example:

```
var entity = context.CreateObject<MyEntity>();
entity.Id = id;
```

Comment: @Ladislav - just curious, i was under the impression when you do a query like `ctx.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.OrderId == 1)`, EF will intinctively look in it's internal graph to see if that entity is there first, before going to the DB - so why would you need to wrap all your calls in the `Local` check?

Comment: @RPM: I checked it with SQL profiler and read about it some articles and it doesn't. It always executes DB query and after data retrieval it checks if the object with the same key already exists. If it exists it returns already existing instance with already loaded data (unless you change loading strategy of the query). If it doesn't exists it materializes new object and adds it to context. Check Julie Lerman's (EF guru) blog: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/looking-at-ef4-ctp5-in-parts-part-3-easy-access-to-in-memory-entities/

Comment: @RPM: Btw. my code for extracting loaded entity from ObjectContext internal storage is based on some example from a book EF4 Recipes: http://apress.com/book/view/9781430227038

Comment: @Ladislav when creating the dummy objects, can they be assigned to other object's properties? Will they be considered unmodified when saving changes?

Comment: @Ladislav - thanks for the links. I already have both Julie's and the EF recipe books. :) Guess i must have glossed over/forgot those things...

Comment: @Diego - If you use Attach the dummy object is considered as Unchanged - it will not be modified. You can assign them to other attached objects but be aware that there can be some other problems when working with them. Personally I don't use them.